# replace text emotions with images

Tags: php

Peace be upon you every body

i searched about replace text emotions with images

found a sultion but it have a probelm

```
    <?php
     function emoticons($text) {
             $icons = array(
                     ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" />',
                     ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />',
                     ':/'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo3" />',
              );
            return strtr($text, $icons);
     }

     echo "http://stackoverflow.com good site:) :-)";

     ?>
```

it output: ( i don't want it to make that )

```
     "http<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo3" />/stackoverflow.com good site<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" /> <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />"
```

i want to output

```
     "http://stackoverflow.com good site:) <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />"
```

---

i think that it should have space before or after the text then replace it

in another question same of this the right answer was

```
             foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
              $icon = preg_quote($icon);
              $text = preg_replace("~\b$icon\b~",$image,$text);
             }
```

but i used it but the result doesn't have any images

please help me, 
Thanks for stackoverflow && all :)

**UPDATE :**

i modified the function and worked fine, but want to listen to your opinion 
if i use it in chat message will be good ? or will face problems ?

```
      function emoticons($text) {
           $icons = array(
                          ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" class="emo1"/>',
                          ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" class="emo1"/>',
                          ':/'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" class="emo3"/>',
                     );   
            $text = " ".$text." ";       
            foreach ($icons as $search => $replace){
             $text = str_replace(" ".$search." ", " ".$replace." ", $text);
            }
           return trim($text);
      }

      $str = ":)http://stackoverflow.com good site:) :-)";
      echo emoticons($str);
```

Comment: Does your input string have HTML code too, or just links like this?

Comment: no it only links and text ( chat message ), i'm use htmlentities to replace html codes

Comment: i mean that it replace any of the emotions even if it was in a link, i want to replace it if there space before the emotion or after it, understand me ?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add `://` to your list:

```
'://' => '://',
```

And replace it with the same string.

Because `strtr` replaces longest keys first the URLs won't be affected

---

Well, if you only want to replace icons preceded by space you can try with regular expressions:

```
foreach($icons as $icon => $image)              
  $text = preg_replace('#(?:^|\s)(' . preg_quote($icon) . ')(?:\s|$)#', $image, $text);
```

This will match any icons that are preceded by a space / or are at the start of the string, and are followed by a space / or are at the end of the string.

But I don't see why you would want that, text like `foo:)` should be considered a smiley too. FYI I almost never prepend spaces to emoticons:)

Comment: sorry i rewite the question in a wrong way
i mean the problem that it output 
     "http<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo3" />/stackoverflow.com good site<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" /> <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />"
, i want to stop it to make that

Comment: ok preg_replace worked fine, but if i put $str = ":)http://stackoverflow.com good site:) :-)"; echo emoticons($str); it replace the first ":)" will replace it with image too and it isn't have space after it, i want to replace if it have space after it or before it, i'm working for chat project and want to replace emotions in message like fb ( to be the idea clear )

Answer (score 2):

How about this, it will only replace if it is either as the start of the string or is following a space:

```
function emoticons($text) {
    $icons = array(
        ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" />',
        ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />',
        ':/'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo3" />',
    );

    foreach ($icons as $search => $replace)
        $text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#", $replace, $text);

    return $text;
}

$str = "http://stackoverflow.com good site:) :-)";

echo emoticons($str);
```

Outputs:

```
http://stackoverflow.com good site:) <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace ' with " like this one:

`':)'    =>  "<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" />",`

if not working try this:

`":)"    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="emo1" />',`

Comment: sorry you didn't understant me, i mean that it replace any of the emotions even if it was in a link, i want to replace it if there space before the emotion or after it, understand me ?